# SQL server agent job built on SSIS package not working

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssis, sql-server-agent

I transferred a job from the old SQL Server 2005 to an upgraded SQL Server 2008 R2 instance, and I scripted out everything, changed the data source and other details... "This job should copy some files automatically from stage locations to active directories" but it's not doing that like it was in the old server! So I'm not sure what I'm missing.

It seems that it's been built on an SSIS package as I can see from the file path location.
I'm trying to open this file using the SQL Server Integration Services, hoping to see the details about the stage location and the active directory details but I get an error about "Registration information for this application needs to be updated...", although there is a MS Visual Studio in the remote server and it should be up-to-date!

I don't know anything about Integration Services, and I see something in the code about 
CONNECTION RCSMTP that I didn't change, maybe that need to be changed to this new server SMTP?

Below is the script for this job that's called `elfCopy` which is Electronic Library Format

```
USE [msdb]
GO

/****** Object:  Job [eLFCopy]    Script Date: 12/30/2013 10:51:54 ******/
BEGIN TRANSACTION
DECLARE @ReturnCode INT
SELECT @ReturnCode = 0
/****** Object:  JobCategory [[Uncategorized (Local)]]]    Script Date: 12/30/2013 10:51:54 ******/
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT name FROM msdb.dbo.syscategories WHERE name=N'[Uncategorized (Local)]' AND category_class=1)
BEGIN
EXEC @ReturnCode = msdb.dbo.sp_add_category @class=N'JOB', @type=N'LOCAL', @name=N'[Uncategorized (Local)]'
IF (@@ERROR <> 0 OR @ReturnCode <> 0) GOTO QuitWithRollback

END

DECLARE @jobId BINARY(16)
EXEC @ReturnCode =  msdb.dbo.sp_add_job @job_name=N'eLFCopy', 
        @enabled=1, 
        @notify_level_eventlog=0, 
        @notify_level_email=0, 
        @notify_level_netsend=0, 
        @notify_level_page=0, 
        @delete_level=0, 
        @description=N'This job copies eLF files & folders from stage locations to active directories.', 
        @category_name=N'[Uncategorized (Local)]', 
        @owner_login_name=N'BIO\WDDocManagement', @job_id = @jobId OUTPUT
IF (@@ERROR <> 0 OR @ReturnCode <> 0) GOTO QuitWithRollback
/****** Object:  Step [RunPackage]    Script Date: 12/30/2013 10:51:54 ******/
EXEC @ReturnCode = msdb.dbo.sp_add_jobstep @job_id=@jobId, @step_name=N'RunPackage', 
        @step_id=1, 
        @cmdexec_success_code=0, 
        @on_success_action=1, 
        @on_success_step_id=0, 
        @on_fail_action=2, 
        @on_fail_step_id=0, 
        @retry_attempts=0, 
        @retry_interval=0, 
        @os_run_priority=0, @subsystem=N'SSIS', 
        @command=N'/FILE "C:\SSIS\Packages\elfcopy.dtsx" /CONNECTION "BRORPORAP3.WDDocumentManagement";"Data Source=BRORPORAP3;Initial Catalog=WDDocumentManagement;Provider=SQLNCLI.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;Auto Translate=False;" /CONNECTION RCSMTP;"SmtpServer=brutmurex3.bio.ri.redcross.net;UseWindowsAuthentication=True;EnableSsl=False;" /MAXCONCURRENT " -1 " /CHECKPOINTING OFF /REPORTING E', 
        @database_name=N'master', 
        @flags=0
IF (@@ERROR <> 0 OR @ReturnCode <> 0) GOTO QuitWithRollback
EXEC @ReturnCode = msdb.dbo.sp_update_job @job_id = @jobId, @start_step_id = 1
IF (@@ERROR <> 0 OR @ReturnCode <> 0) GOTO QuitWithRollback
EXEC @ReturnCode = msdb.dbo.sp_add_jobschedule @job_id=@jobId, @name=N'WeeklySchedule', 
        @enabled=1, 
        @freq_type=8, 
        @freq_interval=2, 
        @freq_subday_type=1, 
        @freq_subday_interval=0, 
        @freq_relative_interval=0, 
        @freq_recurrence_factor=1, 
        @active_start_date=20110701, 
        @active_end_date=99991231, 
        @active_start_time=100, 
        @active_end_time=235959, 
        @schedule_uid=N'c406cae9-49b7-40dd-9438-cef44160f562'
IF (@@ERROR <> 0 OR @ReturnCode <> 0) GOTO QuitWithRollback
EXEC @ReturnCode = msdb.dbo.sp_add_jobserver @job_id = @jobId, @server_name = N'(local)'
IF (@@ERROR <> 0 OR @ReturnCode <> 0) GOTO QuitWithRollback
COMMIT TRANSACTION
GOTO EndSave
QuitWithRollback:
    IF (@@TRANCOUNT > 0) ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
EndSave:

GO
```

--Then I ran the following from the Command Prompt to see the error descriptions with the help of @billinkc and @Zane:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

F:\>dtexec.exe /FILE "C:\SSIS\Packages\elfcopy.dtsx" /CONNECTION "BRORPORAP3.WDD
ocumentManagement";"Data Source=BRORPORAP3;Initial Catalog=WDDocumentManagement;
Provider=SQLNCLI.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;Auto Translate=False;" /CONNECTION R
CSMTP;"SmtpServer=brutmurex3.bio.ri.redcross.net;UseWindowsAuthentication=True;?
?EnableSsl=False;" /MAXCONCURRENT " -1 " /CHECKPOINTING OFF /REPORTING E
Microsoft (R) SQL Server Execute Package Utility
Version 10.50.2500.0 for 64-bit
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation 2010. All rights reserved.

Started:  9:21:36 AM
Error: 2014-01-02 09:22:38.54
   Code: 0x00000003
   Source: PrepFiles PrepFiles
   Description: There was an exception while loading Script Task from XML: Syste
m.ApplicationException: The VSTA designer failed to load:  "System.Runtime.Inter
opServices.COMException (0x80004005): Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned fro
m a call to a COM component.
   at VSTADTEProvider.Interop.VSTADTEProviderClass.GetDTE(String bstrHostID, UIn
t32 dwTimeout)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.VSTAHosting.VSTAScriptingEngine.EnsureDTEObject()"
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.VSTAHosting.VSTAScriptingEngine.EnsureDTEObject()
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.VSTAHosting.VSTAScriptingEngine.InitNewScript(String l
anguageID, String projectname, String projectext, Boolean bCleanupOnClose)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.VSTAHosting.VSTAScriptingEngine.InitNewScript(String l
anguageID, String projectname, String projectext)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.ScriptTask.MigrateVSAScriptTask(X
mlElement elemProj, IDTSInfoEvents events)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.ScriptTask.LoadFromXML(XmlElement
 elemProj, IDTSInfoEvents events)
End Error
Error: 2014-01-02 09:23:40.42
   Code: 0x00000003
   Source: SetCopyFail SetCopyFail
   Description: There was an exception while loading Script Task from XML: Syste
m.ApplicationException: The VSTA designer failed to load:  "System.Runtime.Inter
opServices.COMException (0x80004005): Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned fro
m a call to a COM component.
   at VSTADTEProvider.Interop.VSTADTEProviderClass.GetDTE(String bstrHostID, UIn
t32 dwTimeout)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.VSTAHosting.VSTAScriptingEngine.EnsureDTEObject()"
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.VSTAHosting.VSTAScriptingEngine.EnsureDTEObject()
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.VSTAHosting.VSTAScriptingEngine.InitNewScript(String l
anguageID, String projectname, String projectext, Boolean bCleanupOnClose)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.VSTAHosting.VSTAScriptingEngine.InitNewScript(String l
anguageID, String projectname, String projectext)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.ScriptTask.MigrateVSAScriptTask(X
mlElement elemProj, IDTSInfoEvents events)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.ScriptTask.LoadFromXML(XmlElement
 elemProj, IDTSInfoEvents events)
End Error
Error: 2014-01-02 09:23:50.24
   Code: 0x00000003
   Source: SetPathFail SetPathFail
   Description: There was an exception while loading Script Task from XML: Syste
m.ApplicationException: The VSTA designer failed to load:  "System.Runtime.Inter
opServices.COMException (0x80004005): Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned fro
m a call to a COM component.
   at VSTADTEProvider.Interop.VSTADTEProviderClass.GetDTE(String bstrHostID, UIn
t32 dwTimeout)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.VSTAHosting.VSTAScriptingEngine.EnsureDTEObject()"
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.VSTAHosting.VSTAScriptingEngine.EnsureDTEObject()
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.VSTAHosting.VSTAScriptingEngine.InitNewScript(String l
anguageID, String projectname, String projectext, Boolean bCleanupOnClose)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.VSTAHosting.VSTAScriptingEngine.InitNewScript(String l
anguageID, String projectname, String projectext)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.ScriptTask.MigrateVSAScriptTask(X
mlElement elemProj, IDTSInfoEvents events)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.ScriptTask.LoadFromXML(XmlElement
 elemProj, IDTSInfoEvents events)
End Error
Error: 2014-01-02 09:23:50.29
   Code: 0x00000003
   Source: PrepFiles
   Description: The Script Task is corrupted.
End Error
Error: 2014-01-02 09:23:50.29
   Code: 0xC0024107
   Source: PrepFiles
   Description: There were errors during task validation.
End Error
DTExec: The package execution returned DTSER_FAILURE (1).
Started:  9:21:36 AM
Finished: 9:23:50 AM
Elapsed:  134.161 seconds

F:\>dtexec.exe /FILE "C:\SSIS\Packages\elfcopy.dtsx" /CONNECTION "BRORPORAP3.WDD
ocumentManagement";"Data Source=BRORPORAP3;Initial Catalog=WDDocumentManagement;
Provider=SQLNCLI.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;Auto Translate=False;" /CONNECTION R
CSMTP;"SmtpServer=brutmurex3.bio.ri.redcross.net;UseWindowsAuthentication=True;?
?EnableSsl=False;" /MAXCONCURRENT " -1 " /CHECKPOINTING OFF /REPORTING E>MyOutpu
t.txt

F:\>dtexec.exe /FILE "C:\SSIS\Packages\elfcopy.dtsx" /CONNECTION "BRORPORAP3.WDD
ocumentManagement";"Data Source=BRORPORAP3;Initial Catalog=WDDocumentManagement;
Provider=SQLNCLI.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;Auto Translate=False;" /CONNECTION R
CSMTP;"SmtpServer=brutmurex3.bio.ri.redcross.net;UseWindowsAuthentication=True;?
?EnableSsl=False;" /MAXCONCURRENT " -1 " /CHECKPOINTING OFF /REPORTING E >MyOutp
ut.txt

F:\>
```

Comment: I ran scripts as an administrator, as few sites suggested. Also, I didn't change anything about the user in both servers, so @Owner_Login_name is the same user.

Comment: what's the error message?

Comment: I found this link.  http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/b52e6d5b-585d-4e7a-aced-1a4a82d1ebdd/the-vsta-designer-failed-to-load-systemruntimeinteropservicescomexception-0x80004005?forum=sqlsetupandupgrade  It seems to have some good links that may help you.

Comment: Ok, so many questions I have but here are a few so I can hopefully help more. ① Most obvious question, so pardon me if you already did this. Did you copy the elfcopy.dtsx object from the old server to the same location on the new server? (C:\SSIS\Packages\elfcopy.dtsx). If you did, then the following would be more questions to attempt to assist...

Comment: ② Are you able to find the BIDS project file for the SSIS package? Look on the old server, if possible, for objects with a .sln extension. The easiest way to ensure all your connections are updated is to edit the package in BIDS - SQL Server Business Intelligence project. ③ Is the server and database names the same as on the old server? I see "BRORPORAP3" as the server name and "WDDocumentManagement" as the database name. If those are not the same the package will fail.

Comment: Sorry for the delay in my reply but I just got back to work after the holidays.

Comment: @EdwardDortland the error message is: "Registration information for this application need to be updated. To update, log on as an adminstrator and run this command:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common\IDE\VSTA.exe/HostID SSIS_ScriptTask/setup"

So I run this suggestion but its the same error keeps popping up and then it tells me:
"There were errors while the package was being loaded. The package might be corrupted.."

Then, it opens up the "Control Flow" page finally where I see the boxes that controls the Execution Flow but still the script is not doing what it suppose to

Comment: @FembotDBA Yes I did copy the dtsx file from the old server to the new one and I created the exact same folder path names as C:\SSIS\Packages\elfcopy.dtsx

When I open the BIDS, I dont see any projects\solutions created at all in the old server, so I end up searching and opening the elfcopy.dtsx file. Nothing else end with an .sln extention, I only see the ISP2.SSISDeploymentManifest file and not sure if thats related or I need to copy that one too to the new server?

Comment: @FembotDBA 
Yes I matched the database name to be the same as "WDDocManagment" but the server names are different as we are upgrading, but not sure where I can change that in the elfcopy.dtsx file?
Thank you so much for you help and advices.

Comment: @KennethFisher Thanks for the useful link, I will definetely try thier suggestions except re-installing.

Comment: I'm wondering if you correctly upgraded the 2005 SSIS package to 2008? I know running it with dtexec should temporarily upgrade it, however, I've seen this fail. Also, Was your previous SQL 2005 32bit by any chance? I don't think that will run by default on your 64bit SQL 2008 setup. You could try running the job step in 32bit. See this link on how to upgrade your package from 2005 to 2008: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280546.aspx

Comment: @EdwardDortland Yes the old SQL Server 2005 is on 32bit server and the new SQL Server 2008 is built on a 64bit environment. So is there away around that to run it? as I'm sure there is more behind just copy and pasting the file between the servers.. I will check the link you provided too as I'm still a beginner and don't know that much outside of SSMS. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

I would advice you to upgrade the package by following [these steps](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280547%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

If after your upgrade you still run in to problems, it could be that your package is using components/drivers that are not available on 64bit. In that case the "easiest" work around would be to have your package use a 32bit runtime.

Open de Job properties and then edit the job step that is calling the SSIS package.

Go to the Execution Options tab and check "use 32bit runtime"
[image]

It adds the switch /X86 to the Dtexec execution string. (please note that this switch will be ignored if you directly run it from the command line.)

However, be aware that in that case, you are running the package in 32bit while not making use of the 64bit benefits. This shouldn't have to be a problem, just something to keep in mind.

Comment: I followed the steps to upgrade it using the Wizard but the problem is that in SQL Server 2005 where the .dtsx file origionaly created and works, doesnt exist when I right click in any node in the Integration Services, nor in the Installation Center but it exists in the SQL Server 2008, you meant I have to upgrade it in the new 2008 SQL Server?
I also tried the approach you showed me in the screen shot, its not doing anything also, can I send you the copy of this dtsx file with the scripted out job? Thanks

Comment: Can I follow these intsturctions without messing up anything in that server: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc176071(v=vs.90).aspx or http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc175414(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: As a follow up question: is there a way to do this in a (job create/update) script?

Answer (score 0):

This answer might be late but for those still having issues regarding the subject just change the Target Server Version on your Project Properties in Visual Studio.  Deploy it again then it will work.

[image]